# SignalR Self Host in Xamarin/Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, xamarin, signalr, xamarin.mac

I'm having problem with example for Self Host SignalR (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host).

I was successful on Windows platform with VS 2013, also I have created all necesarry on Xamarin(Mac OS) include nugget packages and startup. After run it open browser and gives error message:

System.Web.HttpException
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Details: Requested URL: /
Exception stack trace:
`at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x001a4] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-mono-3.2.6/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.6/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/StaticFileHandler.cs:121 
  at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00098] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-mono-3.2.6/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.6/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/DefaultHttpHandler.cs:101 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator6.MoveNext () [0x00d9c] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-mono-3.2.6/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.6/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1365 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-mono-3.2.6/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.6/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:932`

I hope it's something obvious. I can share code on request, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a mobile device?  Or on a Mac?

Comment: I did on Mac, I use starter Xamarin edition.

Comment: I gave up on signalr on mono, it was a constant back and forth of working then broken, as it's not getting tested on mono, luckily for me I didn't really need it's features, and was able to switch to nancyfx self hosting, which is very smooth on windows and mono.

Comment: I wanted to base on this feature, thanks for advising nancyfx I will look at tonight.